# Custom auth lambda trigger not configured

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to achieve a classical login/register with react and amplify.
I don't want to use the amplify-react components but only the Auth methods from amplify.

I also want to auto-confirm the users so I plugged a pre-signup lambda function.
Everything is working but I still have this error.

I have tried to unplugged my custom lambda function without any effect.

Here is my function:

```
  handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      await Auth.signUp({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
        attributes: {
          email: this.state.email,
        },
      });
      await Auth.signIn({ username: this.state.username, password: this.props.password });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
```

The error is triggered by the call to signIn after signUp

[image]

Does anyone know what this error message means ?

Answer (score 6):

You must provide the required attributes, username (non-empty) and password (can non-empty)
Make sure the username and password variables are not empty (e.g: null or '').

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when I was accidentally passing in a empty or undefined password so make sure your not doing that however your issue could be different.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have created an appClient on your user pool and have enabled `Enable lambda trigger based custom authentication (ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH)`. It searches for a lambda trigger but you don't have set any.